# Не работает клавиатура

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Что я делаю здесь не так

```
import vk_api
import time
import random
import json
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotEventType, VkBotLongPoll

token = "token"

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

vk._auth_token()


def message(text):
    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": str(
        text), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})


keyboardmenu = {
    "one_time": False,
    "buttons": [
        [
            {
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                    "label": "Играть"
                },
                "color": "positive"
            }],
        [{
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                    "label": "Описание"
                },
                "color": "primary"
            },
        ]
    ]
}

keyboardmenu = json.dumps(keyboardmenu, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
keyboardmenu = str(keyboardmenu.decode('utf-8'))

keyboardmenu2 = {
    "one_time": False,
    "buttons": [
        [
            {
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                    "label": "Такой то режим"
                },
                "color": "positive"
            }],
        [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                "label": "Такой то режим"
            },
            "color": "primary"
        },
        ]
    ]
}

keyboardmenu2 = json.dumps(keyboardmenu2, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
keyboardmenu2 = str(keyboardmenu2.decode('utf-8'))

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, id)

menutext = "Если ты здесь первый раз прочитай описание"

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.object.text.lower() == "старт":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "message": str(menutext), "random_id": 0, "keyboard": keyboardmenu})
            if event.object.text.lower() == "Играть":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "message": "Выберете один из режимов", "random_id": 0, "keyboard": keyboardmenu2})
```

Что бы я не изменял бот реагирует только на команду старт а на последующие по типу "Играть" не реагирует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя стоит .lower где "Играть".

То есть - ты вводишь 'играть' как угодно и боту будет приходить значение 'играть' в низком регистре. А там в сравнении `if event.object.text.lower() == "Играть"` стоит в высоком регистре

поменяй на `if event.object.text.lower() == "играть"`